# If vs If used with OR NOT

Tags: grammaticality

> I don't know if she loves me.

Vs

> I don't know if she loves me **or not**.

Could we use only if in the above sentences, without the use of "or not"?

What's the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no difference between them, but, we usually use "*if*" without "*not*".

> I don't know **if** she loves me.
>
> I don't know **whether** she loves me **or not**.

This is just a difference of usage.